# How to reset the channel in Hyperledger Fabric to genesis block to reuse?

Tags: testing, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-caliper

I have a test `Hyperledger Fabric` environment using docker and caliper.

I have installed the fabric from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric.

I want to reuse the started test network in `fabcar` folder, but using `networkDown.sh` to stop the network and start it again is very time consuming.

Is there a way to reset the fabric blockchain to its first state or genesis block without recreating it, so I can run a new `Caliper` test on it?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no supported way of resetting a channel on peers and orderers to genesis blocks. However, you may create a new channel if that helps.